# Fantasy novel where first death is celebrated

Tags: story-identification, novel

I can't remember what this book is. In it, a particular culture of people (who may or may not be human) celebrate each individual's first death as a coming-of-age ritual. I think that the person is intentionally killed by members of the community as part of the ritual, since they all reincarnate in some way. This novel is probably aimed at middle-grade readers. I can't remember any other details.

Comment: Do you remember when you read this book?  Did the book seem old at the time, or relatively new?  Was it a short story in an anthology perhaps?

Comment: Beyonders, no quote but there is a Wizard born race that regrow via seeds. They celebrate the first death

Comment: @GarretGang Yep, that’s it. Thanks!

Comment: @GarretGang - If there’s not another question with that as an accepted answer, why not write up an answer? If not, I can write one: I recognized this, but I wasn’t sure about it.

Comment: I don’t understand how this is a duplicate. Both questions have the same answer, but there is no overlap in details given.

Comment: @Neithan This site has a [policy](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/31394) to close story-ID questions as duplicates if and only if they have the same (confirmed) answer. ([Even if](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10052/31394) one answer is a series and the other is a book in that series, as long as one question can be satisfactorily solved by reading the answers to the other.) Please remember that **having your question closed as a duplicate isn't any kind of penalty**. It's a reasonable question, with many upvotes; it just happens to have been answered before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this has gone 36 hours without an answer I'll expand [Garret Gang's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172674/fantasy-novel-where-first-death-is-celebrated#comment463709_172674) into an answer. The book is *[A World Without Heroes](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1220082)* from the Beyonders series by Brandon Mull. The people who die and are reincarnated are the Amar Kabal. In chapter 18 Jasher tells Jason and Rachel:

> Jasher paused, regarding them with icy blue eyes. “‘Amar’ means ‘seed.’ The Amar Kabal are the People of the Seed.” He turned his head and lifted the roll of hair. At the base of his skull was a raised portion of flesh the size of a walnut.
> Jason winced. It looked like a huge cyst. “What’s it for?”
> “The amar is the vehicle of our immortality. It dislodges at our death, granting new life when planted in the earth.”
> “You mean you grow?” Rachel asked in amazement. “Like a plant?”
> “Buried in fertile soil, the man grows from the seed within a few months. Less fertile soil requires more time. If my seed dislodged in extremely arid terrain, I might never be reborn."

And there is indeed a ceremony to mark their first death:

> Jasher laughed as if the idea were absurd. “No, we are reborn into the prime of adulthood, the age at which we first die. Our First Death is a ceremony held around age twenty."